# How to retain precision when converting from float32 to float?

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7, floating-point, precision

I have a `numpy.float32` object that I want to encode as JSON. The problem is that when I convert to a native python `float`, I lose the precision of the value.

Example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [4]: np.float32(295.96).item()
Out[4]: 295.9599914550781
```

However, if I first convert to string, then to float, the precision is retained.

```
In [3]: float(str(np.float32(295.96)))
Out[3]: 295.96
```

Is there a way to retain my precision without having to go through a string first?

Why does `str(np.float32(295.96))` seem to retain the precision but `np.float32(295.96).item()` (or `float(np.float32(295.96))` or `np.asscalar(np.float32(295.96))`) does not?

Note: I cannot assume that the precision will always be `.01`. I need to retain the native precision of the data.

Comment: You're not losing precision in the float32->float conversion. Most of the precision loss occurs when you create the float32. The float32->float conversion just makes that precision loss visible.

Comment: You can't, because `float` is a `float64`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to store 64 bits of precision in a 32-bit value. In python, `float` is 64 bit (what is referred to as a `double` in C). As a demo, everything is OK with 64-bit floats:

```
>>> d = 295.6; dn = np.float64(d)
>>> (d, dn)
(295.6, 295.95999999999998)  # numpy prints out more digits than python
>>> d == dn  # but these are still the same
True
>>> d - dn
0.0
```

But if you try and use 32 bits, you drop precision

```
>>> d = 295.96; fn = np.float32(d)
>>> (d, fn)
(295.96, 295.95999)
>>> d == fn
False
>>> d - fn
8.5449218545363692e-06
```

---

> Why does str(np.float32(295.96)) seem to retain the precision

`str(np.float32(295.96))` looks like it retains precision because `np.float32.__str__` rounds (in base 10) for convenience. It just so happens that when rounded, it exactly matches the text you typed in your code. As a result, it has exactly the same value.

Comment: What is special about float -> float32 -> str -> float that makes it seem like it is retaining the precision?

Comment: Got it. So in order for this to work I have to make sure my source data is `np.float64`.

Answer (score 2):

You incorrectly assume that what you see in console is what really happens. The result you see (i.e. the rounding) is just for you = the one who looks at the console. This is how printing of floats is implemented unfortunately (IMO confusing).

The underlying float is always correct, e.g.

```
In [4]: a = np.float32(295.96)
In [5]: a
Out[5]: 295.95999
In [6]: import json
In [7]: json.dumps(a.item())
Out[7]: '295.9599914550781'
```

Comment: The rounding is not just for you. (Part of) the rounding is the difference between `float` and `double`